# What's the best place to level up before the World of Ruin?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I'm not to the World of Ruin yet and I want to level up, can anyone tell a good place to grind?

Comment: Do you really have to ask? It's usually the same process with any game. Find a place with enemies that gives high XP and preferably can be defeated with relative ease.  Or maybe mix in enemies that drop money or other valuables. Usually, it's the last area you were just in or if endgame, some highly inaccessible place.

Answer (score 1):

Probably going to get the best XP gains right before you go to world of ruin, so that would be the Floating Continent, before you trigger the point of no return.